# Why did the designers of ColdFusion decide to index arrays from 1 rather than 0?

Tags: coldfusion, history

I'm just curious about this really, does anyone know why they broke convention on this one?

Thanks,
Ciaran

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@Cory: You'd be surprised to know who lurking on StackOverflow. :-)

You are very much right. The original design of CFML was to allow non-programmers to build complex web applications. ColdFusion\CFML was the first language designed specifically for building web applications. Back in 1995 the web was mostly static HTML and your typical 'web developer' wasn't doing too much programming. The language itself was designed to be as simple as possible which is why it's still one of the fastest/easiest languages to learn.

It can lead to a bit of confusion, especially when ColdFusion code interacts directly with Java or .NET. However, it's just become one of those 'quirks'. The decision was revisited back in 2000/2001 when CF was rebuilt as a Java EE application, but backward compatibility prevented the change.

Answer (score 12):

There's two conventions, the one common to most programming languages, and the one common to most nonprogrammers.  They were probably aiming at the people who don't start counting with 0.

Comment: Well put. That same dichotomy persists in other areas too, such as WYSIWYG editors, and drag-drop file manipulation versus scripts.

Comment: This is a false dichotomy, but you made the point in a far more succinct fashion than I :)

Answer (score 11):

If I had to guess, it's because ColdFusion was aimed to appeal to the novice, and 1-based arrays might make more sense - the first item is number 1, second is number 2 etc.

It's us computer scientists who are weird!

Answer (score 6):

Well, unless we have any of the original designers, it's going to be tough to do anything but speculate. But having used CF in a previous life, I have some ideas.

If you look at the original language, it was designed for RAD type development for people who wanted to build dynamic applications without a lot of complexity. I still remember the joy when they finally released User-Defined Functions so I didn't have to use tags everywhere.

Based on that, then it would make sense that aspects of the language people had to deal with - such as arrays - they would make more "friendly". To me, seeing array[0] makes perfect sense. But to people new to the paradigm who haven't learned that, it wouldn't make any sense. Why would I access an object at position "0"?

The funny thing is that now that CF is Java in the backend, you actually have to deal with cases where your index starts at 1, and cases where it starts at 0. So by trying to be helpful, they actually added in more complexity as the language has grown.

Answer (score 6):

As a different spin on it, let's ask why in some languages the array index starts at zero?  For counting discrete objects (like array elements), this makes little sense and is not natural from a human perspective.

This originally seemed to stem from languages like C (although I'm not suggesting it first arose in C: I don't know, and it doesn't matter for the purposes of this) in which the language and its programming is rather closely coupled to memory management (`malloc`, etc).  Some C language conceits map rather closely to what's going in in memory under the hood.  Variables are an example of this: as well as variable names, we're always busying ourselves with the memory address the variable is at (or *starts at*) with pointers and the like.

So we come to arrays in C, and those are indexed in such a way that there's a series of elements which reside in memory, starting at the base memory location of the array variable, and each element is offset by the size of the data type (eg: a char is one byte, etc). So to find each element in the array in memory, we do this:

```
arrayBaseAddress + (whichElementItIsInTheArray * sizeOfDataType)
```

And one really does actually find oneself thinking like this when doing stuff in C, because it maps rather closely to what the computer has to do under the hood to find the value the code wants.

So the `whichElementItIsInTheArray` is used to offset the memory address (in units of     `sizeOfDataType`).

Obviously if one starts the array index at 1, it would be offset in memory by one `sizeOfDataType`, for all intents and purposes wasting a `sizeOfDataType` amount of memory between the `arrayBaseAddress` and where the first element actually resides.

One might think that this hardly matters, but in days of yore when all this was being implemented, memory was like gold: it could not be wasted like that.  So one might think "OK, well just offset `whichElementItIsInTheArray` by -1 under the hood, and be done with it.  However like memory, clock cycles were gold, so instead of wasting processing, the idea was the programmer would just need to get used to an unnatural way of counting.

So there *was* a legitimate reason to start arrays at index zero in these situations.

It seems to me (and this is getting into editorial slant now) when subsequent "curly braces" languages came out (like Java) they simply followed suit whether it was really relevant still or not, because "that's the way it's done".  Rather than "that way makes sense".

On the other hand, more modern languages, and ones further removed from the inner workings of the computer, someone stopped to think "why are we doing this?", and "in the context of this language and its intended uses, does this make sense?".  I agree here than the answer is - firmly - "no".  The resource wastage to offset the array index by -1, or simply just ignore the zeroth element's memory is no longer a relevant consideration in a lot of circumstances.  So why make the language and the programmer have to offset the way they naturally count things by one, for a purely legacy reason?  There is no legitimate reason to do so.

In C, there is an element of an array `a[0]`.  This is the *first* element of the array (not the "zeroth" element), and if that's the full extent of the array, it's length is *one*.  So the idiosyncratic behaviour here is on the part of the programming language, not on the part of the way things are counted / enumerated "in real life" (which is where most of us reside).  So why persist with it?

Some people here have countered this "where to start the index" argument with "well when we're born, we're not ONE, we're ZERO".  This is true, but that's measuring a continuous thing, and is not the same.  So is irrelevant to the conversation.  An array is a collection of discrete items, and when measuring the quantity of discrete items (ie: counting them), we start at one.

How this adds to the conversation?  Well it doesn't much, but it's a different way of looking at the same thing. And I suppose it's a bit of a rationalisation / reaction to this notion some people have that starting array indexes at 1 is somehow "wrong".  It's not wrong, from a human perspective it's more right than starting them at zero.  So let the human write the code like a human would, and get the machine to make sense of it as needs must.  Basically it's only for legacy technological limitations that we ever started counting them from zero in the first place, and there's no need to perpetuate that practice if we no longer need to.

All "IMO", of course.

Answer (score 5):

Count the number of fingers you have on one hand.  Did you start counting with 0 or with 1?

Abstract ideas that closely parallel real life are always more easily understood and applied (ex: think of a physical "stack" and then of the abstract data structure).

Comment: zero always zero. My kid in kindergarten also had to tell its teacher counting starts at 0. Look at the age of children, bankaccount, nr of cars you own, nr of times you are married, etc, etc.
Starting to count at 1 is an indication you are loosing touch with reality.

Comment: @GvS: As opposed to /losing/ touch...and not learning to spell properly. I doubt your counting skills based on this lack of basic English skills.

Comment: @GvS, you are talking nonsense. A child's age is never 0, it's already 9 months old when it's born and its age is then measured in seconds, then minutes, hours, days, weeks etc. Never 0, always a positive number. And many people's bank accounts count from a minus number downwards :p

Comment: @GvS: So the first dollar in your bank account is dollar number 0?  The first car you buy is considered car number 0?  The first time you are married is considered wife number 0?  It simply makes no real-life sense to number the first item of a collection as zero.  Zero means NO items.

Comment: When I open my bankaccount, It does have € 0,- on it, after that, I can start putting money on it. Sorry I'm no native English speaker/writer, but the message was clear ;-) And naturally if you need to enter the kids age it is 0 years (not always months, etc is available to choose from)

Comment: And before you are married the first time, you are married 0 times. Before you own a car, you own 0 cars. Yes, counting starts as 0.

Comment: And now for counting fingers: Make a fist -> 0, eject thumb -> 1, add finger -> 2, ...

Comment: @GvS: Your fist is not a finger.  Your first finger is finger number ONE.  An array initially starts off with zero elements, but the first element you put in the array should be element number ONE.

Comment: @Shane: mmm, there you have a point. OK, you convinced me. Counting should start at 1.

Comment: Counting starts from 0, but the first element is element number 1.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of starting arrays at 0 was popularized with the C language. Older languages such as FORTRAN and COBOL started counting arrays at 1 (actually called Tables in COBOL).

Answer (score 2):

There is no convention on the starting point of an array. Most Basics start at 1 also for example. Some languages let you start the array wherever you like, or allowarray indexes to be enumerations etc (Ada for example). C used the notion of sting at 0 and many languages have followed, but not all do. One reason why they don't is that arrays starting at 1 is far more intuitive.

Comment: As David says, most Basics start arrays at 1. At the time when CF first emerged it was competing with Classic ASP, which was/is typically coded using VBscript, a subset of Visual Basic.

Comment: @James, VBScript was an odd one. If you asked for an array of size 50, it would give you a 51 element array that started at element 0. That menat you could start at 1 if you wanted to and not run past the end of the array, or you could start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Even within the programming world of Java APIs there is an interesting exception the 0-based counting: The JDBC API. It starts counting with 1, much to the surprise of every programmer doing her first database access.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it wasn't just a layman's thing... I think that most people approaching any web-language have at least fiddled with javascript (and the same was true 10,15 years ago). 0-based indexes weren't quite so foreign.

The thing that I love about languages that start indexes/positions (for strings) at 1 is that you can do things like

```
<cfif find("c","cat")>
```

which evaluates to `true` if c is found, and it will be.

whereas a 0-based language like javascript

```
if ("cat".indexOf("c")) {
```

evaluates to `false`, so you need to say something like `if ("cat".indexOf("c") >= 0) {`

However, translating between languages is a minor nuisance that mustn't be forgotten, because forgetting to do so, or forgetting to pad your arrays can lead to a failure in data translate, and switching between the two styles can lead to frustration.

I think, had Allaire known where the web would be eventually and how client and server can really work together, we'd have 0-based indexes.