# Change array start index when using ListToArray

Tags: arrays, list, coldfusion

When I convert list into array, the values are inserted starting from index 1. Index 0 is left empty.

Why is this happening, and more importantly, is there a way to change it so that it starts from 0 index?

Example:

```
<cfset myList = "A,B,C,D" />
<cfset myArray = ListToArray(myList) />
<cfdump var="#myArray#" />
```

Comment: (Edit) No. As others mentioned, CF arrays use base 1. So there is no index 0. Why do you want to change it? ie What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: yourStructure[0] = "something" will work! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cause ColdFusion Arrays start at one.  Are you actually referncing the 0 position and not getting an error?

[Why did the designers of ColdFusion decide to index arrays from 1 rather than 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420510/why-did-the-designers-of-coldfusion-decide-to-index-arrays-from-1-rather-than-0)

Comment: `you could actually reference the zero in an array` -- what? How's that?

Comment: @Sergii: Wasn't saying you could, just putting that in response to the original question (Eleeist made it sounds like he could reference the zero poisition without an error "Index 0 is left empty")

Comment: @Sergii: I edited my question to make my statement less ambiguous.